# How to set size of string column using service.xml or Service Builder?

Tags: service, size, liferay

Pre-history: I get JDBCExceptionReporter `data exception: string data, right truncation` exception on update of entities.

I have found that this means, the data is too big for the specified `varchar`.

In the `service.xml` the column is specified like:

```
<column name="message" type="String"/>
```

I have found in Liferay's source code for `ServiceBuilder` this fragment:

```
else if (colType.equals("String")) {
    Map<String, String> hints = ModelHintsUtil.getHints(
        _packagePath + ".model." + entity.getName(), colName);

    int maxLength = 75;

    if (hints != null) {
        maxLength = GetterUtil.getInteger(
            hints.get("max-length"), maxLength);
    }

    if (col.isLocalized()) {
        maxLength = 4000;
    }

    if (maxLength < 4000) {
        sb.append("VARCHAR(" + maxLength + ")");
    }
    else if (maxLength == 4000) {
        sb.append("STRING");
    }
    else if (maxLength > 4000) {
        sb.append("TEXT");
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how can I define the `max-length` for my columns?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to modify your `portlet-model-hints.xml` file that you should find under:

```
docroot/WEB-INF/src/META-INF/portlet-model-hints.xml
```

In here you can define `hint` values such as:

```
<hint-collection name="TEXTAREA">
    <hint name="max-length">500</hint>
</hint-collection>
```

Then find the column(s) you want to apply this `hint` in the same file and it should look like this:

```
<field name="your_column_name" type="String">
    <hint-collection name="TEXTAREA" />
</field>
```

or you can as well directly write like this, if there is just one column with the specified hint of `max-length`:

```
<field name="your_column_name" type="String">
    <hint name="max-length">500</hint>
</field>
```

Then you need to run `build-service` again and when you deploy your portlet your DB table should be updated to reflect this change.

I hope this answers your question!

There are other `hints` and a list can be found in this [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customize+DB+Column+Sizes#section-Customize+DB+Column+Sizes-Model+Hint+Values), I just showed `max-length` here as it sounds like that's the one you need.

The complete file would look something like the following if you had one table, with one column. Yours will most likely be a lot longer!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model-hints>
    <hint-collection name="TEXTAREA">
        <hint name="max-length">500</hint>
    </hint-collection>
    <model name="com.mynamespace.model.MyModelClass">
        <field name="myColumn" type="String">
            <hint-collection name="TEXTAREA" />
        </field>
    </model>
</model-hints>
```